# Subscription For Physical Prouducts Without Set Time Period

Tags: recurring

We have a number of books that are printed at irregular intervals. Someone come subscribe and choose which previous volumes to receive. Then they are sent each volume as it is printed. We are using Authorize.net and Paypal.

I am very confused on what type of product I should be creating. The initial subscription can have a zero price, but I do need to capture CC details at Authorize so that I can charge for future purposes.

Any advice?